# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Could not connect database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I'm having problems by connecting to my database which was created on phpmyadmin... I'm using MAMP as a local server.
I've checked several things even the "config.ini.php" file, and the data there matches with the "user" data of my database, plus the "user" has all privileges granted.
I even tried different alternatives as hostname:
localhost, localhost:3306, 127.0.0.1... even my own ip.

I'm quite lost now... any ideas?
Here's the code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "mypassword";
$mysql_database = "mydatabase";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysqli_select_db($bd, $mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

Comment: MariaDB? Dont use root user.

Comment: Just a bit of a side note here: You should use a more precise variable for the connection. The "bd" was a bit misleading for me, since those 2 letters are often used as the French version of "base de données", which means "database" in English. I thought you had that database declaration as the 1st argument. So you can see how it can be a tad confusing.

Comment: You need to find out why exactly it failed you by using `mysqli_connect_error()` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: It's 3am here so I'll check that function tomorrow... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your PHPmyadmin and run the below query in Mysql DB

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdbname.tablename TO 'user'@'localhost';**

After that run the query, **FLUSH PRIVILEGES**

You can also try 
 **GRANT USAGE ON yourdbname.tablename TO 'user'@'localhost';****
 After that run the query, **FLUSH PRIVILEGES**

If you still cant access you can once verify in the users tables if there is no N on any of the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Note: it should follow the sequence :
1. host name
2. user name
3. password
4. database name

This is important while writing, so it should be written as follow.

```php
<?php 
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$database = "akshata"; 

$data= mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database); 
if($data) {
 echo "database connected"; 
} else {
 echo "database not connected"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: <?php
       
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "akshata";

 $data= mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

if($data)
{
    echo "database connected";
}

else
{
    
    echo "database not connected";
}
 
?>

Answer (score -1):

Well did you set a passwort?
or created a User?

If not just try

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";

$mysql_user = "root";

$mysql_password = "";

$mysql_database = "mydatabase";

The basic on Wamp/Xamp is that (for me, i think for everyone?)
If i missunderstood the Question, I'm sorry!

Comment: I created 1 user with its respective password and also gave a password to "root"... the one that I use on my code is the one that appears described on the "config.ini.php" file, which is the same one where I gave a password to "root"...

Comment: did u think about using myadmin and create the user there?

Comment: I created the users on phpmyadmin after creating the database.

Comment: I just checked after on the config.ini file to see if everything was equal

Comment: hmmm could you make a screen or something of your myadmin users?

Comment: I made it like this:
**Saltyy localhost Yes ALL PRIVILEGES Yes**